# Queue implementation using Array in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, integer, queue

I have implemented an integer type Queue using an array in C++ as:
This is not a circular queue so we don't have to bother for the empty space after filling it once and then deleting some values.

```
class IntQueue
{
    private:
        int *queueArray;
        int queueSize;
        int rear, front;

    public:
        IntQueue(int);          // Constructor
        ~IntQueue(void);
        void Enqueue(int);
        int Dequeue(void);
        bool isFull(void);
        bool isEmpty(void);
        void Display(void);
};  

// Constructor
IntQueue::IntQueue(int size)
{
    queueArray = new int[size];
    queueSize = size;
    rear = -1;
    front = -1;
}  

// Destructor
IntQueue::~IntQueue(void) 
{    
    delete [] queueArray;
}  
// Enqueue function
void IntQueue::Enqueue(int num)
{
    if (isFull())
    {
        cout << "The Queue is full.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        rear++;
        queueArray[rear] = num;
    }   
}

// Dequeue function
int IntQueue::Dequeue()
{
    int num;
    if (isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "The Queue is empty.\n";
    }
    else
    {
        front++;
        num = queueArray[front];
    }
    return num;
}

//isFull function
bool IntQueue::isFull(void)
{
    bool status;

    if (rear == queueSize - 1)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}

//isEmpty function
bool IntQueue::isEmpty(void)
{
    bool status;

    if (front == rear)
        status = true;
    else
        status = false;
    return status;
}

// Display function
void IntQueue::Display()
{
    if(isEmpty())
    {
        cout << "The Queue is empty.\n";
    }

    for(int i = front++; i <= rear; i++)
    {
        cout << "queueArray[" << i << "] = " << queueArray[i] << endl;
    }
}  
// Main function
int main()
{
    int option, queueCapacity, value;


    cout << endl << "Enter size of queue: ";
    cin  >> queueCapacity;

    IntQueue *queue = new IntQueue(queueCapacity);

    Menu:
    cout << endl << "Queue implementation using Array" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "1. Enqueue"    << endl;
    cout << "2. Dequeue"     << endl;
    cout << "3. Display Queue" << endl;
    cout << "4. Display Menu" << endl;
    cout << "5. Exit"    << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------" << endl;

    YourOption:
    cout << endl << "Your option: ";
    cin >> option;

    switch(option)
    {
        case 1:
            // Enqueue
            cout << "Enter value to enqueue: ";
            cin  >> value;
            queue->Enqueue(value);
            goto YourOption;

        case 2:
            // Dequeue
            int data;
            data = queue->Dequeue();
            cout << data << " is dequeued!";
            goto YourOption;    
        case 3:
            // Display
            queue->Display();
            goto YourOption;    
        case 4:
            goto Menu;  
        case 5:
            exit(0);
        default:
            cout << "Invalid option!" << endl;
            break;
    }
    delete queue;
    return 0;
}
```

The variable `rear` is initially `-1`. I have checked `isFull()` function as if `rear` is equal to the size of `Queue`, then the queue is full, not otherwise. However, to check queue emptiness, I compared if `rear == front`, then empty, not otherwise. But after executing it, by opting `2` from the menu, it displays some random value sometimes and the message i.e., "The Queue is empty".
What is the problem in this example?

Comment: You do remember the difference between assignment using `=` and comparison for equality with `==`? Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude even after correcting this `=`, Dequeue is not working

Answer (score 0):

```
void enqueue(int x)
{
    //cout << "Enter the DAta " << endl;
    //cin >> x;
    if (front==(rear+1)%size)
    {
        cout << "Queue Is overflow::" << endl;
        return;
    }
    else if (rear==-1&&front==-1)
    {
        //cout << "enter the To EnQueue :" << endl;
        front = rear = 0;
        queue[rear] = x;
    }
    else if (rear==0 && front==0)
    {
        rear = rear + 1 % size;
        queue[rear] = x;
    }
    else
    {
        rear++;
        queue[rear] = x;
    }

}
```

Comment: use this one for Enqueue function

Comment: Have you provided Enqueue function for a Circular Queue?

Comment: it is circular Enqueue function

Comment: I don't need a circular queue function

Answer (score 0):

Your queue is working properly but you have need to check some variable values like in the `Enqueue(int num)` function you have forgot to update the variable `front=0`

```
void IntQueue::Enqueue(int num)
{
   if (isFull())
   {
     cout << "The Queue is full.\n";
   }
   else
   {
     rear++;
     queueArray[rear] = num;
   }   
 }
```

because at the initial time when you display the values `front=-1`.

So, add the `front=0` in the `enqueue` function like this,

```
void IntQueue::Enqueue(int num)
{
  if (isFull())
   {
     cout << "The Queue is full.\n";
   } 
  else
   {
     front=0;
     rear++;
     queueArray[rear] = num;
   }   
}
```

Hope you got it. if you have any confusion comment it.